# i3-wm keep resizing my VM

Tags: virtualbox, i3, manjaro

On manjaro 17 with virtualbox 5.1.6 or 5.1.8 as soon as I install the guest additional driver to my Windows 7 VM i3 start resizing automatically the VM windows to its minimum making it unusable.

- It does not happen if I load a linux VM.
- It does not happen if I load the windows VM using gnome from Ubuntu.

The bug happens once you are on the desktop and might be related to the use of graphic driver/virtual graphic card not used similarly in the preceding steps.

**EDIT**
Did not reproduce on an other computer with different configuration, it is probably hardware related

Comment: So you think it's because if i3? Tried with other window managers?

Comment: Well, there are two possible 'hacky' workaround I see. First one is to use VM on a separate screen (desktop) and forcing it to go fullscreen (std. shortcut is `mod+shift+f`). The second one is to make it a floating window - std. shortcut is `mod+shift+space`). Wonder if this would help - please let me know.

Comment: As I am just starting with i3 and hadn't time yet to go through a proper tutorial, I would be ashamed if the second solution work! Thanks a lot I'l try that tonight when I am back home.

Comment: It did not work. The windows was actually already floating, but forcing to have it fit to i3 tilling made things worst. Full screen is unusable as well.  I found a workaround.

Comment: at the moment (or, since 2016) there is a bug with resizing in 5.1.6 https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/15863?cversion=0&cnum_hist=2
... but the answers below point to the right direction (remember to install appropriate guest additions for your version)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In vritualbox menu bar, go to View > Vritual screen > pick a resolution.
The screen stop to be automatically resized permanently

Answer (score 1):

Found this topic by googling the same issue.
The solution is very simple:
 There is an option for virtualbox named `Autoresize guest display`. Turning it off cause work vbox with i3 just fine.